# Create Wrap Text on Cell FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

How to add wrap text on **Cell FPDF** ?

Example my code is :

```
$pdf->AddCol('name',50,'My Name','L');
```

**name :**  data from database. 
**50** : width of cell.
**My Name** : Title Cell.
**L** : Align of Cell from database.

Answer (score 0):

Use multicell

```
MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])
```

Example:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,15,"This text is too long and will be wrapped each line with height 15");
```

Here

height **15** means not height of all cells.It's height of a **single line wrapped**

width **0** means the cell **extends up to the right margin**. 
You can define a fixed width here if you want.