# wrap text of a cell in PDF report with database driven data using FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I've a table whose data is brought and printed on the PDF report. The problem is that Trainee Name column's text is inserting with attached cell (Training Title).

I've gone through [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542244/wrap-text-in-fpdf-in-php), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460699/create-wrap-text-on-cell-fpdf), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477372/make-text-wrap-in-a-cell-with-fpdf?rq=3) but couldn't understand what to do?

Here is my PHP Code:

```
    <?php
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php'); // Adjust the path based on your project structure

include "my-connection.php";

// Fetch data from the "items" table
$query = "SELECT
            tp.participant_id ID,
            tree.name Trainee, 
            trpr.training_title,
            tp.training_date,
            tp.is_attended,
            tp.remarks
            FROM
            training_participants tp
            LEFT JOIN trainees tree ON
            tree.trainee_id = tp.trainee_id
            LEFT JOIN training_profiles trpr ON
            trpr.training_profile_id = tp.training_profile_id
            LEFT JOIN trainers trs ON
            trs.trainer_id = tp.trainer_id
            LEFT JOIN training_focal_person trfpo ON
            trfpo.focal_person_id = tp.focal_person_id
            WHERE
            tp.is_deleted = 'true'
            ORDER BY
            tp.participant_id
            DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($myConn, $query);

// Create PDF
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add Heading on the Report
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Items List', 0, 1, 'C'); // 'C' stands for center alignment
$pdf->Ln(10); // Add some space after the heading


$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 16);

// Set column names
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->Cell(10, 10, 'ID', 1);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Trainee', 1);
$pdf->Cell(80, 10, 'Title', 1);
$pdf->Cell(25, 10, 'Date', 1);
$pdf->Cell(10, 10, 'Att', 1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Remarks', 1);


$pdf->Ln(); // Move to the next line

// Set data from database
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $pdf->Cell(10, 10, $row['ID'], 1);


    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, $row['Trainee'], 1);
    //$pdf->MultiCell(40, 10, $row['Trainee'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(80, 10, $row['training_title'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row['training_date'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(10, 10, $row['is_attended'], 1);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 10, $row['remarks'], 1);

    $pdf->Ln(); // Move to the next line
}

// Output PDF
$pdf->Output();

// Close database connection
mysqli_close($myConn);
?>
```

In the visited URLs, I've seen one thing to use

> $pdf->MultiCell

But even by using it, the line is broken after the cell and all the alignment gets mixed up.

Please guide me that how to make it happen?

Thank you.

Comment: The script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) may help.

Comment: For more advanced tables, you can take a look at [fpdf-easyTable](https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable).